# Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a recipe organizer as a sample project for a class. I'm not very experienced with DRF other than using some very basic functionality. Here's the objective:

Create a new Recipe with associated Ingredients. Create the Ingredient objects at the same time as creating the Recipe object.

**models.py:**

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="This is a quick description of your recipe")
    directions = models.TextField(help_text="How to make the recipe")
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient_data in ingredients_data:
            Ingredient.objects.create(**ingredient_data)
        return recipe
```

This successfully creates the Recipe object AND the Ingredients objects in the database, but doesn't associate the list of Ingredients with the Recipe. I assume this is because when I run `ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')`, the `validated_data` dictionary gets its Ingredients removed, so when I create a new Recipe using `validated_data`, there aren't associated ingredients.

However I can't seem to figure out a way to keep ingredients associated with the recipe.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I figured out that ManyToMany relationships can't be established until all of the uncreated objects have been created. (See the Django Docs [page on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).)

Here's the working code:

**serializers.py**

```
class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for ingredient in ingredients_data:
            ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient['name'])
            recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
        return recipe
```

### UPDATE:

Per request of @StevePiercy, below is my `update()` code. **However**, I haven't looked at this in years and have no idea whatsoever if it is correct or good. I haven't been working in Python or Django for some time now, so take this with a grain of salt:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')

    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
    instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
    instance.directions = validated_data.get('directions', instance.directions)
    instance.photo = validated_data.get('photo', instance.photo)

    ingredients_list = []

    for ingredient in ingredients_data:
        ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient["name"])
        ingredients_list.append(ingredient)

    instance.ingredients = ingredients_list
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: What do you do with ingredients_list?

Comment: @iankit Whoops, I realized I had pasted in a snippet from my update() method instead. I've fixed it to reflect the correct code. Thanks!

Comment: I am noticing when I try to do something similar to this, I am getting "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input." on the browsable API. Any tips on how to work around this?

Comment: @bobbyz would you please be so kind to share your `update()` method, too?

Comment: Above code will work only if the name field is unique

Answer (score 14):

Below is a helpful example for this question.

Change that part of code like this:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
    recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)

    for ingredient in ingredients_data:
        ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient['name'])
        recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
    return recipe
```

And this is the method to edit, cause an error when you want to edit.

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
    instance.name = validated_data['name']
    instance.description = validated_data['description']
    instance.directions = validated_data['directions']

    for ingredient in ingredients_data:
        ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient['name'])
        recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
    return instance
```

Here is a link with an example. This code is similar to another answer, but if you want to try the code without any problems, you can use this repo. Good luck!
[DRF Nested serializers](https://github.com/fercreek/DRFNestedSerializers)

Comment: How did this get down voted when the code looks the same as the accepted answer?

Comment: I would suggest this small change for robustness:

            `ingredient, created = ingredient.objects.get_or_create(**ingredients_data)`

That way the dictionary is passed as a **kwargs to the constructor, thus abstracting the actual class structure. 

Otherwise, this answer helped me a lot! Thanks!