# Return nested json response

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

My models.py:

```
class CUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'), default=timezone.now)

class SL(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)

class Key(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default = 'Unnamed')
    sl_uuid = models.ForeignKey(SL, related_name='ssls')
    user = models.ForeignKey(CUser)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^getstate/$', views.GetStateView.as_view(), name='getstate'),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

serializers.py:

```
class SLSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    queryset=SL.objects.all()
    class Meta:
        model = SL
        fields = (
            'name',
            'uuid',
            'last_updated',
        )

class GetStateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sls = SLSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = tuple(User.REQUIRED_FIELDS) + (
            User.USERNAME_FIELD,
            'last_updated',
            'sls',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            User.USERNAME_FIELD,
        )
```

views.py:

```
class GetStateView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.GetStateSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.request.user
```

I want to get json response as:

```
{
    "email":"abc.com",
    "first_name":"abc",
    "last_updated":"2016-11-02T02:12:36Z",
    "sls": [
         {
            "name":"123",
            "last_updated":"2016-11-02T02:12:36Z",
            "uuid":"ac9d496d-62ba-45a1-a1ec-e1eca571b656"
         },
         {
            "name":"23",
            "last_updated":"2016-11-02T02:12:36Z",
            "uuid":"ac9d496d-62ba-45a1-a1ec-e1eca571b656"
         }
    ]
}
```

I am gettings the SL entries as empty:

```
{
  "first_name": "Monica",
  "email": "abc@abc.com",
  "last_updated": "2016-11-02T02:12:46Z",
  "sls": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

It uses token authentication and will use the `key` table to select all SL's for the requesting user(which I am getting using self.request.user) and will be sending user details along with the SL entries.
But I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: @Sayse it's not duplicate of above question. The relationships b/w tables is totally different. I am having difficulty in serializing the data according to the relationships. So I would request u to look at the question  once again. I am a beginner to the framework,  so I'm having a hard time resolving this.

Comment: But your view never calls any serializer. It will never return any kind of model data.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have specified the serializer_class serializer_class = serializers.GetStateSerializer. Isn't this the way?

Comment: Well, usually, but you've overridden `get`, which is what would usually call the serializer. So you would need to call it yourself. (Note that overriding `get` or `post` is usually a bad idea, for precisely this reason.)

Comment: Or you can call the superclaas `get`, which is probably what you meant to do instead of returning `request.user` (which makes no sense and is the cause of the error you see).

Comment: @DanielRoseman The reason for overriding get was that I wanted to make sure that the request is made with a query_parameter(last_updated) and then compare it with the value stored in the DB. Is there some other way to validate this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127167/discussion-between-toothie-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 0):

update your serializers like below

```
class SLSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SL
        fields = (
            'name',
            'uuid',
            'last_updated',
        )

class GetStateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sls = SLSerializer(queryset=SL.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = tuple(User.REQUIRED_FIELDS) + (
            User.USERNAME_FIELD,
            'last_updated',
            'sls',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            User.USERNAME_FIELD,
        )
```