# django rest framework model foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models

```
class Order(models.Model):
     fields...

 class OrderItem(models.Model):
     fiels...
     order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items')
```

and I have two serializers:

```
class CreateOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        resource_name = 'order-item'
        fields = ('order', 'count')
   .....
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     items = CreateOrderItemSerializer(many=True)
     class Meta:
         model = Order
         resource_name = 'order'
         fields = ('id','items')
```

I posted order with items array like this:

```
{
    'ordername': 'foo',
    'items': [{
        'name': 'foo1',
        },{
        'name': 'foo2',
        },
      ]
}
```

But I have error:

```
"order":["This field is required."]
```

how can I first create order later create items with this orderid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my own answer to question:
first add extra_kwargs to item serializer:

```
class CreateOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        resource_name = 'order-item'
        fields = ('order', 'count')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'order': {'required': False},
        }
```

after add create method to orderserializer:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for item in items_data:
        item_name = item['name']
        item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order,name=item_name)
    return order
```

Comment: Thanks! Spent way too long looking for this solution. The REST framework documentation sucks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good solution here [Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers)
which this is almost the same problem here.

The difference is here `ForeignKey` is used instead of `ManyToMany` which will cause `required field error`

adding `extra_kwargs` solved this problem, there is another way which is add null=True to foreignkey field

```
order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', null=True)
```