# Nested serializer concept for post and update

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

i am using nested serializers concept in python django.For get() method i used  a serializer as below

```
class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_musician = AlbumSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Musician
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'instrument', 'album_musician')
```

but how can i write a nested serializer concept for the post and update concept without overriding `update` and `create`.

Comment: Did you read this, [DRF's Writable nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: DRF documentation providing nice example for nested creation and nested updation.

Comment: [DRF's nested update example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-update-methods-for-nested-representations)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: You can't write/update a nested serializer ***without overriding corresponding methods***

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializer with post. But you need to override the create method of MusicianSerializer.

```
   class MusicianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        album_musician = AlbumSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Musician
            fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'instrument', 'album_musician')

            def create(self, validated_data):
                album_musicians = validated_data.pop('album_musician')
                musician = Musician.objects.create(**validated_data)
                for album_musician  in album_musicians:
                    AlbumMusicain.objects.create(musician=musician, **album_musician)
                return musician

`
```