# Django REST Framework - SerializerMethodField is null on serializer.save()

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and REST Framework. I want to save with serializer by data. I called to `serializer.save()`. But saved model field is null with `animal` field in `HumanSerializer`. I want define `animal` field by `SerializerMethodField` and want to save model. How to do it?

Serializer:

```
class HumanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    animal = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = (
            'id',
            'animal', # <- animal is ForeignKey of Animal model
        )

    def get_animal(self, lead):
        # blah blah blah
        pass
```

A save process:

```
data['animal'] = 1
serializer = HumanSerializer(
    data=data,
    context={'request': request},
)
if serializer.is_valid():
    human = serializer.save()
    human.animal # <- animal is null. but delete SerializerMethodField then not null
```

Comment: Please look this question, seems like similar case in question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SerializerMethodField` is always a read only field. You can add another field for the writing purposes.

**Example**:

```
class HumanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    animal = SerializerMethodField()
    animal_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='animal',
        queryset=Animal.objects.all(),
        write_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = (
            'id',
            'animal',
            'animal_id'
        )
```

Then, pass `animal_id` in the request data to save the `Animal` along with the `Human`.

**Ref**:
* [PrimaryKeyRelatedField docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Answer (score 1):

First, a `SerializerMethodField` is read only by design. So you cannot use it to accept the Human data. Secondly, creation of nested objects cannot be handled by the serializer by default. You have the override the create method and handle the creation of the nested objects. Check the docs on how to implement [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: this is the correct way. You will need to override some methods on your serializer to achieve writable nested serializers. there are some packages that handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

SerializerMethodField is read only by default. So when your serializer will validate data, it will chuck out 'animal' key from data for saving into models.

To overcome this, one way is to override serializer's validate function so that it will not remove animal key from your data. Example:

```
class HumanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    animal = SerializerMethodField()


    def validate(self, data):
        animal = data['animal']
        # Any validation code for animal, if required
        validated_data = super(HumanSerializer, self).validate(data)
        validated_data['animal'] = animal
        return validated_data


    class Meta:
        model = Human
        fields = (
            'id',
            'animal',  # <- animal is ForeignKey of Animal model
        )


    def get_animal(self, lead):
        # blah blah blah
        pass
```