# DRF - Serialize multiple models

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework, nested

please help! How can I can get this JSON

```
{
  "value": 9998,
  "startDate": "01-03-2019T06:59",
  "endDate": "31-03-2019T23:59",
  "days": 11111111,
  "name": "Juices",
  "Stores": [
         921,
         923
    ]
  }
```

Because , with my code I only retrive this JSON

```
[
    {
        "AS400Promotion": 9998,
        "days": 11111111,
        "name": "Prueba",
        "promotionType": 999
    }
]
```

How can I do it? I read the drf documentation but it didn't work, what I'm doing wrong?
here is my code
my models.py

```
  class Store(models.Model):
     modular = models.ForeignKey(Modular, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     store_nbr = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, help_text="Numero 
     Tienda")
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Nombre de sucursal")

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Campain(models.Model):
    AS400Promotion = models.IntegerField(default=9998)
    days = models.IntegerField(default=1111111)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, related_name='stores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    promotionType = models.IntegerField(default=99)
```

here are my serializer.py

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('modular', 'store_nbr', 'name', 'address', 'commune', 
'region', 'open_status', 'manager_name')

class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stores = StoreSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ('value1', 'days', 'name', 'stores', 'promotionType')
```

my viewsets.py

```
class CampaignViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Campaign.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CampaignSerializer
```

and my routes.py

```
router.register(r'campaign', CampaignViewSet)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not with DRF, you need to brush up on how database relations work. I assume you have a many to one relation(one campaign many stores), so the **foreign key needs to be in the Store model and not the Campaign model**
like this

```
class Store(models.Model):
     campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, related_name='stores', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then use nested serializer as you've done already

```
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ('modular', 'store_nbr', 'name', 'address', 'commune', 
'region', 'open_status', 'manager_name')

class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stores = StoreSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = ('value1', 'days', 'name', 'stores', 'promotionType')
```

Always keep in mind the name of the field for the nested serializer(StoreSerializer in your case) should match your related_name in your model(Store model in your case) for the foreign key(campaign field in your case)

Answer (score 1):

So with respect to your first query about changing the field name in json have a look at the value example, you can change others in same way.

To get the foreign key serialized create an object **store** in CampaignSerializer. A good example is here 
[Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers)

I can't see start_date and end_date in your model so I can't comment on that

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   store = StoreSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
   value = serializers.IntegerField(source='AS400Promotion')

class Meta:
    model = Campaign
    fields = ('value', 'days', 'name', 'store', 'promotionType')
```