# Django Rest Framework inserting and updating writable nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I trying to insert and update a writable nested serializer with Django Rest Framework, following examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers). But it doesn't work, because somehow after I execute **`serializer.is_valid()`** it lose the reference from **`serializer.validated_data`** like if it never was sent.

What could I having doing wrong?

My models

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'User'
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'Users'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Institution(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=255, null=False)
    country = models.CharField(db_column='country', max_length=255, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Institution'
        managed = True
        verbose_name = 'Institutions'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Institutions'
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My serializers

```
class InstitutionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Institution
        fields = '__all__'
        datatables_always_serialize = ('id', 'name', 'country')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    institution = InstitutionSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        institution_data = validated_data['institution']
        instance.institution = Institution.objects.get(pk=institution_data['id'])
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'is_active',
            'institution',
        )
        datatables_always_serialize = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_active',
            'institution',
        )
```

My view

```
class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsSuperUserPermission,)

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        params = Q()
        if 'search[value]' in request.GET and request.GET['search[value]'] != '':
            params = Q(username__icontains=request.GET['search[value]']) |\
                     Q(first_name__icontains=request.GET['search[value]']) |\
                     Q(last_name__icontains=request.GET['search[value]']) |\
                     Q(email__icontains=request.GET['search[value]']) |\
                     Q(institution__name__icontains=request.GET['search[value]'])

        queryset = User.objects.filter(params).select_related().order_by('id')
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = User.objects.filter(pk=request.GET['pk']).select_related()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ('create',):
            self.permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data['id'])
        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():

            if 'password' in serializer.validated_data:
                serializer.validated_data['password'] = make_password(serializer.validated_data['password'])

            serializer.update(user, serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Edit.

I submitting data like this:

```
{
    "username": "BLA",
    "email": "BLA@BLA.com",
    "first_name": "BLA",
    "last_name": "BLA",
    "institution": 1,
    "is_active": true,
    "password": "bla12345"
}
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: No errors, it just not update the field

Comment: any problem while creation?

Comment: Actually it just clear the field after .is_valid(), and then not change the value for instante, whitout any other errors or exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem, using JPG idea. I just add an else using a PrimaryKeyRelatedField to allow serializer to get reference from the model from id.
There might be another solution, bu this one works and looks better than multiple serializers.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            self.fields['institution'] = InstitutionSerializer()
        else:
            self.fields['institution'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Institution.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 3):

### Why this problem?

In your update payload, you are providing the **`institution`** data as an integer which represents the **`PK`**. But you've also defined a nested serializer **`InstitutionSerializer()`** inside **`UserSerializer()`** class. So, DRF expects a **`dict`** like object (DRF probably raise some error by mentioning so. I'm not sure why it's not happened in this situation).

### What is the solution?

Since you are passing the **institution id**, I assume, you need the ***nested output only on `HTTP GET` requests***. So, override the **`__init__()`** method of the **`UserSerializer()`** class and restrict the nested serializer usage to only **`HTTP GET`** requests
Here is the code

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            self.fields['institution'] = InstitutionSerializer()

    institution = InstitutionSerializer() # remove this

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        institution_data = validated_data['institution']
        instance.institution = Institution.objects.get(pk=institution_data['id'])
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'is_active',
            'institution',
        )
        datatables_always_serialize = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'is_active',
            'institution',
        )
```

---

### UPDATE-1

Change your **`partial_update()`** method of **`UserViewSet`** class as below,

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.data['id'])
    serializer = UserSerializer(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True, context={"request": request}) # change is here <<<
    if serializer.is_valid():

        if 'password' in serializer.validated_data:
            serializer.validated_data['password'] = make_password(serializer.validated_data['password'])

        serializer.update(user, serializer.validated_data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: it returns an error: if self.context['request'].method == 'GET': KeyError: 'request'

Comment: There is no request in the constructor

Comment: Something change, I have now a response {"institution":["Invalid hyperlink - No URL match."]}

Comment: After couple test I found it this doesn't work, it simple solve the problem when I listing data from GET request, which broke with overridden constructor, but when creating of update got the same results. My issue is, when I execute validate data with is_valid(), the serializer dumps reference for institution. I'm doing a PATCH, so.. is like I never sent it and it just not update.

Comment: I've already explained why `validated_data` doesn't contain the `institution` section

Comment: That way the only solution would be two serializers? One for querys and other for create or update?

Comment: overriding the **`__init__()`** method in a proper way is another solution.  I'm not sure why my solution isn't working.