# Django REST POST null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have error after send post request for creating new item in **user** field - *it return null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (61, My Company, {2,3}, 2020-08-08 10:41:54.355926+00, My desc, 2, 2, null).* . My data for send in JSON

```
{
    "name": "My Company", 
    "members":[2, 3] , 
    "user": 2, 
    "description": "My desc", 
    "status": 2, 
    "theme": 2
}
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user=serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model=Account
        fields='__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            if self.context['request'].method in ['GET']:
                self.fields['members'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        except KeyError:
            pass

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def get_members(self, obj):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=obj.members)
        return AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
        
class CompanyListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You want to write nested relations. Look  here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Oh thank you. But this is difficult for my understanding (

Comment: Show your post request data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at other questions of yours, it seems like you  need  `user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)` for GET request only. If so,

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            if self.context['request'].method in ['GET']:
                self.fields['members'] = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
                self.fields['user'] = UserSerializer()
        except KeyError:
            pass

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
        
    def get_members(self, obj):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(id__in=obj.members)
        return AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True).data
```