# django rest framework POST json array

Tags: json, post, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i'm creating simple API to load json to database.

Part of json:

```
....
           "updateOn": "31-01-2021"
        },
        "simulations": [
            {
                "code": "option1",
                "name": "option1_name",
                "is_selected": "false",
                "parameterValues": [
                    {
                        "parameter": "tenor",
                        "value": "36"
                    },
                    {
                        "parameter": "vatFinancing",
                        "value": "yes"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ] ....
```

I dont now how can I save data from array "parameterValues".

Right now I have 2 models

```
class QtSimulations(models.Model):
    code_p = models.ForeignKey(QtOfferParam2, to_field="code", db_column="ext_id", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="simulations")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="name")
    code_s = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_column="code", primary_key=True)
    is_selected = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="is_selected")

    class Meta
        db_table = 'ZZ_QT_SIMULATIONS'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class QtParameterValues2(models.Model):

    simulation_code = models.ForeignKey(QtSimulations, to_field="code_s", db_column="simulation_code", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="parameterValues", primary_key=True)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, db_column="parameter")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, db_column="value_p")

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'ZZ_QT_PARAMETER_VALUE_2'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

and serializer

```
class SimulationsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    parameterValues = ParameterValuesSerializer(many=True)
    code = serializers.CharField(source = 'code_s')
    class Meta:
        model = QtSimulations
        fields = ('code', 'name', 'is_selected', 'parameterValues')


class OfferDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    quotation = QuotationField(source='*')
    simulations = SimulationsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QtOfferParam2
        fields = ['quotation', 'simulations']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        simulations_data = validated_data.pop('simulations')
        print(simulations_data)
        code = QtOfferParam2.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for simulations_data in simulations_data:
            simulations_data['code_p'] = code
            QtSimulations.objects.create(**simulations_data)

        return code
```

If I remove 'parameterValues' from "SimulationsSerializer" everything is save.

How can I save data from 'parameterValues'array to QtParameterValues2?

I tried do somthing similar to simulation but i get error

**Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use parameterValues.set() instead.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: thanks for response, I found solution.